# A straightforward answer to using session variables in MVC Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, session-variables, asp.net-mvc-views

I am having difficulties utilizing session variables in MVC views. In my example below, the If condition in my view is not met when I set the IsLoggedIn session variable to true via the controller. Note: I trimmed some of the irrelevant code for easier reading. Thanks in advance!

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 0)
    {
        JobSummaryModelHelper jobDetails = new JobSummaryModelHelper();
        jobDetails.Id = id;  

        jobDetails.jdata = .....

        return View(jobDetails);
    }

    public ActionResult Authenticate()
    {
        .....

        int usercount = db.JobBoardUsers.Where(u => u.userid.Equals(un) && u.passcode.Equals(pc)).Select(u => new AccountModel() { uid = u.id }).Count();
        if (usercount > 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Session["IsSignedIn"].Equals(true);              
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", jobDetails);
```

View:

```
 .....

@if (Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsSignedIn"]))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">Logged in!
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller's action is not setting the session variable to true.

To do that you need to replace

```
HttpContext.Session["IsSignedIn"].Equals(true);
```

with

```
HttpContext.Session["IsSignedIn"] = true;
```

The Equals method does not change the a value, it is a method which tells you if 2 things are equal.. it has a return value, but you're doing nothing with it

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this line

```
HttpContext.Session["IsSignedIn"].Equals(true);
```

Should either be this

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["IsSignedIn"] = true;
```

or this

```
Session["IsSignedIn"] = true;
```

Reason - you need to access the session on the current HttpContext.  By either leaving off HttpContext (the controller has a reference to the current HttpContext) or explicitly identifying it `HttpContext.Current`, you are ensuring that you are setting the correct session values on the current HttpContext.  Also, I made a change to how you are setting the property, I am not sure if the `.Equals()` will do what you want it to do.  However, I do know using the explicit `=` sign will.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `HttpContext.Current.Session[IsSignedIn] = true`
and then access it the same way on the view. (`HttpContext.Current.Session[IsSignedIn]`)